# Do some Stack Exchange sites really allow joke answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-site, site-specific

(It looks like [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43969/why-are-some-jokes-closed-and-deleted-and-others-are-allowed) is about question posts specifically rather than answer posts.)

[Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) has a specific report reason for joke/troll answers. I cannot believe that Stack Exchange which even [removes 'thanks'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and is of course generally far more strict than Quora (which in some ways is kind of like [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) anyway) allows this. Does Stack Exchange lack such a policy that applies to every site? Is it really [up to each site to decide whether or not to allow joke/troll answers](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/update-yes-or-cunninghams-law-joke-answers-allowed-seriously)?

Btw, there may be another law involved. See [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/update-yes-or-cunninghams-law-joke-answers-allowed-seriously#comment1132_962):

> Ah, but the problem here is rather [Poe's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law). Even if the joke is outrageous, some simply won't get it. I'm taking bets pkr's answer above falls under it. Thus, whereas I might put in puns, popcultural snippets and anecdotes into my answers, I'd avoid outright joking. –
> [Hauke Reddmann](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11144/hauke-reddmann) Feb 20 '21

Comment: A decision like this is normally left up to the moderators of individual sites.

Comment: See also: [*Is humor allowed in answers?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16496/579398)

Comment: You might also be interested in browsing the [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) tag on [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions), as an example of where joke answers (and questions) used to be on-topic

Comment: [*Yahoo Answers* is a thing of the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers#Closure). Someone saved the meme [Yahoo Answers will be remembered for](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28679/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156977/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325394/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41976/282094 and against: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210572/282094 - it's lack of research that we oppose.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, each Stack Exchange community decides how the scope of the site is defined, what are the close reasons, and what are the general guidelines.

However, there is one common denominator: [the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you believe some post/comment violates the Code of Conduct, it should be flagged.

Based on that I would strongly distinguish troll answers (which is not acceptable behaviour) and "joke" answers (which may or may not be acceptable). Overall, jokes by themselves are fine and are not against the current CoC.

The acceptability of jokes is definitely community-dependent, and discussed in more detail in the [Meta post on jokes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43969/why-are-some-jokes-closed-and-deleted-and-others-are-allowed) you have already linked.

Comment: *... jokes ... are not against the current CoC*. That is a joke, right? Or are we using different version of the CoC? Because I read this [*Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). Let's hope my joke is careful enough to survive the comment flaggers. Maybe a smiley face will save me ;)

Comment: @rene "...be careful with jokes" — is exactly why I conclude that they are fine, unless they are going against CoC for one or many other points. Jokes are dangerous, as it is extremely easy to become rude and unfriendly.

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty hard to write a joke answer without it being downvoted and deleted. After all, we're generally here to impart knowledge rather than mislead.

There are a couple of well-known successful answers on Stack Overflow, but [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1038015) has had to be locked [to prevent people who don't get the joke from editing it or flagging it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions?page=2). This has the unfortunate side effect that you can't vote on the answer any more.

[The other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642314/1038015) has been [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1642314/1) to make it abundantly clear that it is a joke. It's arguable of course that that has meant that it is somewhat less funny now.

So the answers have to have truth in them, but impart that knowledge in a humorous way and that's hard to do successfully. If it's insufficiently clear that it is humorous or it is only a joke then history tells us that it won't survive.

Comment: There was another joke answer about the [fifth element](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/) of an array, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is clearly "Yes" as the Judaism site has a specific tag and a policy for asking humorous question during the period of Purim. See their policy [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated).

As you can see from the policy it is strictly regulated.

There was an attempt to have something similar on the Spanish site on December 28, the Day of the Holy Innocents and approximate equivalent of the Anglo April Fool's Day on April 1, but it failed to gain popular support. The relevant meta post is [here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/una-vez-al-a%c3%b1o-no-hace-da%c3%b1o-propuesta-para-permitir-preguntas-off-topic) but note it is in Spanish.